# How to generate two random integers such that their running sums have a given ratio

Tags: random

I am trying to generate two random integers each with their own potential range of values.  I keep a running sum of each value, and need to ensure that the ratio between these sums stays within range of a given value.

For each trial, I want both numbers to be random.  Ie. I don't want to generate a single value and then calculate the other value to make the ratio I want.

The best solution I have found is for each trial, to just generate pairs of random numbers until The pair matches my constraints.  However its not guaranteed to find a solution, and may loop for a long time.

```py
import random

XMIN, XMAX = 64, 2500
YMIN, YMAX = 16, 2000
GOAL, THRESH =0.90, 0.03

def trial(sumX, sumY):
  x,y=0,0
  while True:
    x = random.randint(XMIN,XMAX)
    y = random.randint(YMIN,YMAX)
    if abs( (sumX+x)/(sumX+x+sumY+y)-GOAL) <= THRESH:
      return x,y


sumX,sumY=0,0
for I in range(10000):
  x,y=trial(sumX,sumY)
  trial_ratio = x/(x+y)

  sumX, sumY = sumX+x, sumY+y
  sum_ratio = sumX/(sumX+sumY)
  print(f"+({x:5d}, {y:5d}) = {trial_ratio:0.2%}      :     ({sumX:8d}, {sumY:8d})  = {sum_ratio:0.2%}")
```

The snippet is in python, but the language doesn't matter

The above works as expected, however if possible I would like to be able to terminate faster than just making a random guess and throwing out invalid results.

Comment: If you calculate a new acceptable range for each random number (based on the prior numbers) before you generate it, you won't have the "throw out invalid results" problem.

Comment: How big are (XMAX-XMIN) and (YMAX - YMIN)

Comment: @GauravMathur Those values are arbitrary (user selectable), but the values at the top of the snippet wouldn't be abnormal.  The GOAL and THRESH are truly arbitrary between 0 and 1.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Won't this just cause the allowed ranges to converge to a single value?  At which point the values aren't random any more.

Comment: I would imagine that it would have the same effect as throwing away results until you get one that is in range, except that it will work faster.

Comment: (you should probably re-evaluate your assumptions)

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the tip, I was able to figure out how to calculate the xmin,xmax values by assuming that we choose YMAX, or Ymin for y.  I then choose a random x value within that range, and then I can calculate he range of valid values for y given that choice of X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tip from RobertHarvey I was able to calculate possible ranges for x and y for each trial.

I had previously assumed that doing such would cause the possible ranges to converge such that I I would keep getting the same values for `x` and `y`.

First I calculate the absolute extrema of the valid range of `x` by assuming that `YMIN` or `YMAX` is chosen as `y`.  I then randomly select x from within that range.  Finally I recalculate the extrema for `y` given the selected `x` and choose `y` from within that range.

```py
def clamp(val, min_val,max_val):
  return int(max(min_val, min(val, max_val)))

def trial2(sumX, sumY):
  _xmin = -sumX - ((GOAL - THRESH)*(YMIN + sumY))/(-1 + GOAL - THRESH)
  _xmax = -sumX - ((GOAL + THRESH)*(YMAX + sumY))/(-1 + GOAL + THRESH)

  xmin = clamp(_xmin,  XMIN,XMAX)
  xmax = clamp(_xmax,  XMIN,XMAX)
  x = random.randint(xmin,xmax)

  _ymin = ((-THRESH-GOAL+1)*(x+sumX) + (-THRESH-GOAL)*sumY)/(GOAL+THRESH)
  _ymax = (( THRESH-GOAL+1)*(x+sumX) +  (THRESH-GOAL)*sumY)/(GOAL-THRESH)
  ymin = clamp(_ymin,  YMIN,YMAX)
  ymax = clamp(_ymax,  YMIN,YMAX)
  y = random.randint(ymin, ymax)


  return x, y
```

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution could be to pre-calculate all possible combinations and create a list of pairs. Then select random items from that list as many as you want, instantly.

```
var validData = new List<(int, int)>();
for (int i = XMIN; i <= XMAX; i++)
{
    for (int j = YMIN; j <= YMAX; j++)
    {
        var isValid = true;//logic to verify if it is valid
        if (isValid)
            validData.Add((i, j));
    }
 }
```

And then you can simply pick random pairs out of `validData` list.

```
var index = rand.Next(validData.Count);
var pair = validData[index];
```

This solution will guarantee you'll always find a random pair.

Sorry the code is in C#, I don't know Python (yet) :)

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav.  I think this would technically work, but it scales O(n^2) so with large ranges, I think this would probably perform worse than random selection.

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked how big are the numbers :)